# How did Isaac Newton write the integral symbol?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, notation, calculus, newton

Isaac Newton is known as the discoverer of the FTC (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus), so maybe he wrote the integral symbol and derivative symbol. I know he wrote the derivative symbol as $\dot y$ but I cannot find the integral symbol he wrote. How did Isaac Newton write the integral symbol?

Comment: And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Historical_notation

Comment: As far as I think by Wikipedia, Newton's notation is like $\fbox{$x$}=\frac12x^2+\mathit{Const.}$.

Comment: @MIKANkankitsu I would like to know the answer to this also. The tall S $\int$ is agreed to have been invented by Leibniz, so Newton almost certainly didn't use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Newton used both vertical bars ($\overset{|}{x}$) and rectangles ($\boxed{x}$) to denote integrals in his [Quadratura curvarum](https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-ADD-03962/1) published in 1704.

Here, the bar notation is used on the bottom of [page 9](https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-ADD-03962/9) in the linked digital scan (multiple bars would represent multiple integrals):
[image]

This [source](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/calculus/#:%7E:text=In%20his%20Quadratura%20curvarum%20of,rectangle%20to%20indicate%20its%20integral.:%7E:text=In%20his%20Quadratura,this%20entry.%5D) states that the notation did not become popular because the bar could be misinterpreted as a "prime", and a rectangle was difficult to print at the time.

Additional information from post linked by @KurtG. in the comments:

- Newton used $\overset{|}{x}$ to indicate the quantity whos [fluxion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxion) (a *fluent* was a changing value and a *fluxion* was its instantaneous rate of change) is $x$.

In fact, it seems this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton%27s_notation_for_integration) sums everything up very clearly. Given $y=f(t)$,
$$
\overset{|}{y}=\square y=\boxed{y}=\int y\ \mathrm{d}t.
$$

Comment: See also Mauro Allegranza's comments to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1966797/949989) . Maybe you want to compile this all into a more complete answer? I cannot type formulas right now.

Answer (score 7):

The section II.4 Integral Calculus in *[Analysis by Its History](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77036-9)* by E. Hairer and E. Wanner begins with quotations, one of them from a letter by Newton:

> **Newton, letter to Keill, April 20, 1714:**
> And whereas $\mathrm{M^r}$ Leibnits praefixes the letter $\int$ to the Ordinate of a curve to denote the Summ of the Ordinates or area of the Curve. I did some years before represent the same thing by inscribing the Ordinate in a square ...
>
> My symbols therefore ... are the oldest in the kind.